# Choosing graph layout: force-directed or Sugiyama or another

Tags: layout, graph, interface, similarity

I have some data: items and their pairwise similarities.
When user selects item I want to give him some fancy representation of item's neighbors and their connections. It should be readable and easy to catch either common structure or details.

And I go to graphs -- graph communities, graph layouts.
So I have item's neighbors graph, 20-30 nodes. What's next?

1. Too many edges is a kind of noise, so I limit minimum valuable similarity and  total count of edges.
2. I get graph communities (somehow, now it's fastgreedy). They will have different colors on my picture.
3. I should choose graph layout.

First thing I've tried is Fruchterman-Reingold.
[fruchterman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcbTz.png) (I draw gray edge if nodes belong to different clusters.)

Maybe it's quite good, but I have some doubts. And I've tried layered layouts for trees: Sugiyama, Reingold-Tilford.

[sugiyama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojry3.png)

Is it better looking? But that case seems worse:

[sugiyama2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Ptd.png)

So this is main question: what layout would be adequate?

And I hide labels, because it's unclear too: how to get them not to obstruct fancy edges, not to overlap, being easy for perception and etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Now I think that Reingold-Tilford (or Sugiyama) is pretty okay.

It's not okay when some community has too many edges -- I can easily detect it and just decrease number of edges.